# Filter numbers that are closest to target values and eliminate duplicated observations

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter, subset

I have this dataframe:

```
data_a <- read.csv(text = "
date,treatment,stage
1,a,1
2,a,10
3,a,20
4,a,30
5,a,60
6,a,70
7,a,89
8,a,91
9,a,92
1,b,1
2,b,10
3,b,20
4,b,30
5,b,59.8
6,b,60.2
7,b,88.8
8,b,90.2
9,b,92
1,c,1
2,c,10
3,c,20
4,c,60
5,c,66
6,c,70
7,c,80
8,c,85
9,c,85")
```

I need to filter within each `treatment` the observations matching `stage` 10, 60, and 89 (or the observation closest to those target values). The code I have is this:

```
filtered_data <- data_a %>%
  group_by(treatment) %>%
  filter(abs(stage - 10) == min(abs(stage - 10)) |
         abs(stage - 60) == min(abs(stage - 60)) |
         abs(stage - 89) == min(abs(stage - 89)))
```

This code partially does the trick, but there are problems for `treatment` b and c.

In b, two observations have the same difference from the target. So, both observations are filtered in, which is not desired.

In c, two observations have the same value and are closest to the target, and therefore both observations are selected, which is not desired.

The desired output is this:

```
filtered_data <- read.csv(text = "
date,treatment,stage
2,a,10
5,a,60
7,a,89
2,b,10
5,b,59.8
7,b,88.8
2,c,10
4,c,60
8,c,85")
```

Comment: What happened to `7, b, 88.8`? Why do you exclude that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it thusly

```r
library(tidyverse)

crossing(
  data_a,
  target_stage = c(10, 60, 89)
  ) %>% 
  group_by(treatment, target_stage) %>% 
  slice_min(
    abs(stage-target_stage),
    with_ties = F
    )
#> # A tibble: 9 × 4
#> # Groups:   treatment, target_stage [9]
#>    date treatment stage target_stage
#>   <int> <chr>     <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1     2 a          10             10
#> 2     5 a          60             60
#> 3     7 a          89             89
#> 4     2 b          10             10
#> 5     5 b          59.8           60
#> 6     7 b          88.8           89
#> 7     2 c          10             10
#> 8     4 c          60             60
#> 9     8 c          85             89
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

If you expand the grid using `crossing` you can then group by this and find the smallest whilst also removing ties

Comment: On second thoughts, `crossing` with the full dataset is not very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` and `purrr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map_dfr(c(10, 60, 89),
        ~ data_a %>%
          filter(abs(stage - .x) == min(abs(stage - .x)),
                 .by = treatment) %>% 
          slice_min(stage, n = 1, with_ties = FALSE, by = treatment)) %>% 
  arrange(treatment, date)

#>   date treatment stage
#> 1    2         a  10.0
#> 2    5         a  60.0
#> 3    7         a  89.0
#> 4    2         b  10.0
#> 5    5         b  59.8
#> 6    7         b  88.8
#> 7    2         c  10.0
#> 8    4         c  60.0
#> 9    8         c  85.0
```

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(data_a)[
  data_a[CJ(stage = c(10, 60, 89), treatment = unique(data_a$treatment)), 
                on = .(treatment, stage), 
                roll = "nearest", 
                .(date, treatment)], 
  on = .(treatment, date)][
    order(treatment, date)]

#>    date treatment stage
#> 1:    2         a  10.0
#> 2:    5         a  60.0
#> 3:    7         a  89.0
#> 4:    2         b  10.0
#> 5:    5         b  59.8
#> 6:    7         b  88.8
#> 7:    2         c  10.0
#> 8:    4         c  60.0
#> 9:    9         c  85.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `outer()` + `max.col()` to find the closest or farthest values from 10, 60, 89.

```r
library(dplyr)

data_a %>%
  slice({
    mat <- abs(outer(c(10, 60, 89), stage, '-'))
    max.col(-mat, "first")
  }, .by = treatment)

#   date treatment stage
# 1    2         a  10.0
# 2    5         a  60.0
# 3    7         a  89.0
# 4    2         b  10.0
# 5    5         b  59.8
# 6    7         b  88.8
# 7    2         c  10.0
# 8    4         c  60.0
# 9    8         c  85.0
```